# ASP.NET VB Listbox DataBind Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

In my user control, I have a text boxes that I used to create a new membership user. Each listbox has a datasource set to `membership.getallusers()` to fill the listbox. When the listbox index is changed, it populates the text boxes to allow editing. What I want to accomplish is: have each user listbox refresh to show the new user that gets created. Even though I call `databind()` after successfully creating the user, it doesn't update. On the form load I check if `listbox.items.count < 1`, then call `databind()`, which does work correctly. Any ideas?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If ListBox3.Items.Count < 1 Then
        For Each item As MembershipUser In Membership.GetAllUsers(0, Membership.GetAllUsers.Count + 1, Membership.GetAllUsers.Count)
            ListBox3.Items.Add(item.UserName)
        Next
        Label1.Text = ListBox3.Items.Count
        username = ListBox3.Items(0).ToString
    Else
        ListBox1.DataBind()
        ListBox3.DataBind()
    End If
    user = Membership.GetUser
    ListBox1.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers
    ListBox1.DataBind()
    ListBox2.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles
    ListBox2.DataBind()
    ' ListBox3.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers
    'ListBox3.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub ListBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles             ListBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
    txtUsername.Text = user.UserName
    txtEmail.Text = user.Email
    txtQuestion.Text = user.PasswordQuestion     
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try'Creates a new user
        Dim status As System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus
        Membership.CreateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtQuestion.Text, txtAnswer.Text, True, status)
        Label1.Text = "User " & txtUsername.Text & " was created"
        'ListBox3.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.DataBind()
        'ListBox3.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = "Error:" & ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the datasource again before you do the databind, like so:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try'Creates a new user
        Dim status As System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus
        Membership.CreateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtQuestion.Text, txtAnswer.Text, True, status)
        Label1.Text = "User " & txtUsername.Text & " was created"
        'ListBox3.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers()  ' Necessary because the DB has changed
        ListBox1.DataBind()
        'ListBox3.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = "Error:" & ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

When you call databind, you might think that that's the moment the Listbox will call the method you gave it as a datasource, but that's not the case. The moment you assign the datasource, the data is retrieved. When you actually call the Databind-method, the Listbox will create the necessary internal controls

Comment: Awesome that worked. I didn't realize the datasource actually grabs the data. So I take it that databind just loads from the in memory datasource?

Comment: Correct: First you get the data, the databind creates the internal control structure